# 404 not found for a Rest Web service with wildfly

Tags: java, json, rest, maven

I am following this tutorial [Crunchify tutorial](https://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/) to create a Rest web service but I can't get past step 5 since each time it gives me a 404 error. I am using Maven, on eclipse with Wildfly server.
this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>CrunchifyTutorials</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servletclass>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "http://example.com/xml/404.xml"
```

Hope it'll helps you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to set

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

and then go to / in you browser url